# How to set privileges for a user in Django (without using admin)?

Tags: django, django-permissions

I am new to Django and I wanted to set privileges without using admin from my templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#methods:

this is how to programatically add/remove permissions

```
myuser.groups = [group_list]
myuser.groups.add(group, group, ...)
myuser.groups.remove(group, group, ...)
myuser.groups.clear()

myuser.user_permissions = [permission_list]
myuser.user_permissions.add(permission, permission, ...)
myuser.user_permissions.remove(permission, permission, ...)
myuser.user_permissions.clear()
```